# Efficiently emulate SQL's group by clause in a programming language like Java or C++ instead of resorting to an RDBMS

Tags: java, c++, sql

I would like to execute on-the-fly SQL GROUP BY on a file that gets uploaded. I don't want to store the file in a database first and then execute the clause because thats just too time consuming for my needs.

What is an efficient algorithm that I can use in Java or C++? Preferably C++.

Thank you in advance for any ideas and answers.

Comment: What will you be doing with your on-the-fly GROUP BY operations?  Will you be performing aggregate calculations, such as max, min, count, average, and sum?

Comment: a GROUP BY clause is too time consuming?

Comment: yes because i dont need the overhead of storing a file in the database first. Want to process it on the fly and not save it or anything.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to just sort the data on the field you'd use in the `group by` clause in SQL.

Grouping has looser constraints than sorting, so in theory it could be marginally faster than sorting, but unless you're dealing with a *lot* of data, you're unlikely to see a speed difference.

The big difference comes when you use SQL's summarizing capabilities. For example, `select x, count(x) from wherever, group by x` will show each value of `x` and the count for each value. For functionality like this, you'd typically use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` in C++, or `HashMap` or `TreeMap` in Java.

Edit:

For a *really* trivial example, let's consider the result of a fairly simple group-by clause, where we want counts of people born in various years. We'll start with raw data like this:

```
last-name<tab>first-name<tab>height<tab>birth-year
```

so (for example) I'd be encoded like:

```
Coffin\tJerry\t70\t1964
```

In SQL, we might use:

```
select birth_year, count(birth_year) 
    from people
    group by birth_year
    order by birth_year
```

For a rough equivalent in C++, we might write code something like this:

```
struct person { 
    std::string last_name;
    std::string first_name;
    int height;
    int birth_year;
};
```

We'd read our data on a bunch of people from a file something like this:

```
 std::ifstream in("people.txt");
 std::vector<person> people((std::istream_iterator<person>(in)),
                             std::istream_iterator<person>());
```

Then we'd collect the data we care about something like this:

```
std::map<int, int> year_counts;

for ( auto &p : people)
    ++year_counts[p.birth_year];
```

Then we could print out the data something like this:

```
std::cout << "Year\tCount\n";
for (auto c : year_counts)
    std::cout << c.first << "\t" << c.second << "\n";
```

Comment: Well, I have files that are 30 - 40 million records each. So Its a lot of data. can you provide an algorithm example? Im new to C.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful! This is in C or C++?

Comment: @ImtiazAhmad: C++. The C standard doesn't include any pre-written collection code, so doing this in C would create quite a bit of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Use guava, It's Function can be used to pull out the group by field, and it's multimap to hold references from the group by to the instances of that item. Example can be found here:
http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=228

```
public class GroupByMultimap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] o1 = new Object[] { 1, "Greg", "Dev" };
        Object[] o2 = new Object[] { 2, "Leo", "Support" };
        Object[] o3 = new Object[] { 3, "Roman", "Dev" };
        Object[] o4 = new Object[] { 4, "Jobby", "Support" };

        List<Object[]> rows = Lists.newArrayList(o1, o2, o3, o4);
        Multimap<String, Object[]> grouped = Multimaps.index(rows,
                new Function<Object[], String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(Object[] item) {
                        return (String) item[2];
                    }
                });

        Iterator<String> keyIterator = grouped.asMap().keySet().iterator();
        while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = keyIterator.next();
            System.out.println("key = " + key);
            Collection<Object[]> dataRows = grouped.get(key);
            for (Object[] o : dataRows) {
                System.out.println(String.format("  %d : %s", o[0], o[1]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```